# Ontario HST Rebate: Is the HST rebate taxable / to be included in one's income?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate, income-tax

Is the HST rebate taxable?

Answer (score 5):

The HST rebate / Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit (OSTTB) is **not** taxable.

Refer to the [Ontario Ministry of Revenue's FAQ on the subject](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq.html#Q11).